Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11. in window system
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\viran\StudioProjects\k_walzy_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11.
      Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
      You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Please [edit] your question and also provide your build files. Make sure to properly format them using a [code block].

okay which build file android/build.gradle?

Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre recent versions of Android Studio include a Java 17 runtime, thus it seems like your Android Studio version is a bit outdated. Or download and install a stand-alone OpenJDK 17 JDK version, install it and set JAVA_HOME pointing to it.
